# SAS Looping through macro variables on an if statement and through multiple datasets

Tags: loops, sas, macros, do-loops

Depending on the value of a macro variable I am looking to output multiple datasets. I am looking to loop this through and I am also looking to do this on multiple input datasets.

```
%macro data_split;

%do i=1 %to %loop;

data work.test_&&mac_var&loop;
set work.input_dataset;
if col = "&&mac_var&loop" then output test_&&mac_var&loop;
run;
%end;
%mend;
```

This outputs a number of tables depending on how many times it loops through and gives the correct output depending on the value of mac_var.

However I'm looking at looping it through a number of input_datasets but when trying to add the second loop I'm having issues.

Another solution I thought would be to simply merge these datasets I want into one dataset.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Show the actual SAS code you want the macro to generate.  Why can't you just put all of the dataset together and avoid the looping?

Comment: Indeed, it is a waist of time to read your complete data set time and again. A data step can generate multiple data sets.

Comment: I've found a solution where I've merged the datasets together and then output them to new datasets depending on a where clause. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up

- macro's `%name` and macro variables `&name`
- your index `&i` and your final value `&loop`

Supposing the macro variables `&mac_var1`, `&mac_var2`, ... and `&loop` are well defined,

```
%let mac_var1 = alpha;
%let mac_var2 = beta;
%let mac_var3 = gamma;
%let loop = 3;
```

this should do the job (I think, because your question is not that clear).

```
%macro data_split;
  data
    %do i=1 %to &loop;
      work.test_&&mac_var&i
    %end;
    ;
  set work.input_dataset;
  %do i=1 %to &loop;
    if col = "&&mac_var&i" then output test_&&mac_var&i;
  %end;
  run;
%mend;
%data_split;
```

But actually, I would rather specify the values of these macro variables as a parameter

```
%macro data_split(mac_var_list);
  %let loop = %sysfunc(countw(&mac_var_list)); *(1);
  data
    %do i=1 %to &loop;
      %let mac_var = %scan(&mac_var_list, &i); *(1);
      work.test_&mac_var
    %end;
    ; *(2);
  set work.input_dataset;
    %do i=1 %to &loop;
      %let mac_var = %scan(&mac_var_list, &i); *(1);
      if col = "&mac_var" then output test_&mac_var;
    %end;
  run;
%mend;
%data_split(alfa beta gamma);
```

(1) the `scan` function exists both as data step function and as macro function, but countw only exists as data step function, so you need `%sysfunc` to call it here.

(2) All `;` between `data` and here are macro code, so this `;` is the one closing the `data` statement.

PS, next time, give much more details in your question.
It is not normal we have to guess what `&&mac_var&i` might mean.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I didn't explain myself correctly but I've found a solution. Next time I'll make sure I explain myself better.